# How is a DNS wildcard a security issue for GitHub Pages?

Tags: dns, web, github

GitHub Pages allows to set up a public page under `<user>.github.io` that can optionally be [customized with a personal domain](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site). In order to do so:

- GitHub must be set up to recognize that an incoming call referred to by a non-GitHub domain should be handled
- the personal domain must have a pointer to GitHub, via a `CNAME` in the domain's zone

At some point in the documentation, there is a [fat warning](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-a-subdomain):

[image]

(EDIT: I updated the example below to a more complete zone following Steffen's answer because I do not understand it)

Let's say that I own `example.com` and the public IP `150.1.1.1`, and I have a wildcard DNS entry:

```
*.example.com. IN CNAME hello.example.com.
hello.example.com. 300 IN A 150.1.1.1
mypageongithub.example.com. IN CNAME myuser.github.io.
```

In other words, something not otherwise defined in my `example.com` zone points to `hello.example.com`.

How can this present a danger of someone using my domain to advertise their GitHub page?

*Note: I posted the question in Information Security rather than superuser.com or another similar site as this is more about identity theft (or misrepresentation) than a technical question about DNS*

Comment: The warning doesn't apply since your zone isn't CNAME-ing a wildcard to GitHub Pages. You're only doing that for a particular unrelated subdomain.

Comment: @amon: this is probably the meaning of this (terribly worded) warning indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the discussion  in comments, the warning of GitHub is against DNS entries such as

```
*.example.com IN CNAME someuser.github.io
```

This is a case where someone would use `example.com` as the baseline for several pages at GitHub and would not be willing to name them all one by one.

In such a case, since `someuser.github.io` ultimately points to a set of IPs in GitHub (`someuser.github.io` does not have a dedicated IP), then a malicious user could piggy-back on `example.com` to point to their page.

The example in my question where the wildcard points to a host in `example.com` is not a problem.

Personal comment: the warning is in a scary red box and should be made IMO more explicit (by GitHub)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> *.example.com. IN CNAME hello.example.com.
> ```

A CNAME is resolved in the client to finally get the IP address. This means Github is not aware that you have a CNAME for `*.example.com` and that `whatever.example.com` resolves to `hello.example.com` using this CNAME. All it knows is that somebody wants to access `whatever.example.com` since this is the name used to access a `github.io` IP address.

If your `<user>.github.io` is only mapped to the name `hello.example.com` then somebody else could create a different `<user2>.github.io` page and map it to `another-hello.example.com`. Both domains resolve in the same target IP address (due to the CNAME) but one will show the contents of `<user>.github.io` while the other will show the contents of `<user2>.github.io`.

Note that this only relevant if you map all subdomains to `github.io` using a wildcard - as it seemed to be from your original question. After the edit of the question it came clear that there is only a single name mapped to `<user>.github.io` and that the wildcard is used for domains which don't map to Github. This is fine and this is also not was Github warned against when reading the warning in the context it was originally published.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, but I do not understand. I updated my question with a full DNS zone, with a wildcard pointing to a `CNAME`, which points to an `A` to have a complete example. I still do not understand how someone can make use of `another-hello.example.com` that will ultimately point to an IP I ultimately own.

Comment: @WoJ: Again, all what Github sees that somebody is accessing `another-hello.example.com` on the IP address of `github.io`. Github does not see any of the CNAME's including the on pointing to `myuser.github.io`, it only sees the result of resolving a the name `another-hello.example.com` to the IP address. Since `myuser.github.io` and `other-user.github.io` are ultimately served by the same servers all what it has is the original domain name given in the TLS handshake and HTTP request, i.e. `another-hello.example.com`. And this mapping could be claimed by `other-user`.

Comment: No, `another-hello.example.com` resolves (though the wildcard) to `hello.example.com`, which resolves (though the `A`record) to `150.1.1.1` (which is my IP). The only case your example would be working would be if  I had the whole wildcard pointing to GitHub (`*.example.com IN CNAME user.github.io`) - which would indeed be a terrible (and unexpected) thing to do, which may very well be the meaning of the warning, in which case it is poorly worded.

Comment: @WoJ: Now I see what you mean. Your original question did not include the mapping of a __single__ name to github.io but included only the wildcard. And I did not properly read your edit. In this case what you have configured is outside of what github is warning against. My understanding of the warning you cite when __taking the context of the warning__ is against using a wildcard to map a domain including all subdomains (wildcard) to github.io. This is not about using wildcards on places in DNS which have no relation to github.io.

Comment: We agree then. As a side note, my initial question (that you quoted) showed a wildcard pointing to a host on example.com, not github.io

Comment: @WoJ: yes, you should nothing about github, but only an example of a CNAME setup with a wildcard. Given that no real domains were used I though this was used to show how you setup wildcard in general and assumed that you setup wildcard to github the same way - since the context of your question was for me about wildcards to github.